# Why won't the FrameLayout I use as my fragment container use full screen width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

For some reason, my frame layout does not extend all the way till the edge of the screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my Activities layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contactInfoFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the layout for the solitary fragment that I am placing in the FrameLayout at run time:

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dialog"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailsLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/Thumbnails"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="97dp">

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.06"
            android:text="Add image" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/shopNameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumberLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Phone" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addressLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addressText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I simply add the fragment in my onCreate method by doing this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_shop);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.contactInfoFragmentContainer) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            ContactInfoFragment firstFragment = new ContactInfoFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.contactInfoFragmentContainer, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }
```

So what is the problem ? When I look at the fragments layout in design view, it looks fine!

[image: Fragment view in android studio]

The problem seems to appear only after adding the fragment to my activities layout (see above code and layout). How should I fix this ?

EDIT: I don't understand why I received a down vote. At the very least you could leave a comment explaining what is wrong with the question.

Comment: whats your activity Layout looks like?

Comment: @dhiku It is specified in the question "Here is my activities Layout:" ...

Comment: Why -1 ? It is a legitimate question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting your `FrameLayout` width to `match_parent`!
Edit:
For `ConstraintLayout`, replace your current `FrameLayout` with:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contactInfoFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
```

And make sure you have `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your root layout declaration in xml.

Comment: Android studio does not let me. When I set it to match_parent it changes it to 368p

Comment: If the `FrameLayout` is inside a `ConstraintLayout`, set the former's width to 0 and set attributes `layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf` and `layout_constraintRight_toRightOf` to `parent`.

Comment: I did that, and now the screen is blank

Comment: I added this to my FrameLayout: app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/parent"

Comment: Did you mean to add it to the frame layout in the activity ? Or in the frame layout of the fragment ?

Comment: `<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contactInfoFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

Comment: Do exactly that and you should be fine.

Comment: No the screen is blank.